# Laravel manually update timestamps returns null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, timestamp

I have an offer with some children.

I want to update expire_time field of each children when their parent expire_time field changed.

but it returns null.

expire_time type is timestamps.

and here is my code in model:

```
if ($offer->childrenOffers->count()) {
        $offer->childrenOffers->each(function (self $childOffer) use($offer) {

            ddd($offer->expire_time); //returns "2018-02-30 23:59:59"
            ddd($childOffer->expire_time); //returns "2018-02-01 23:59:59"

            $childOffer->expire_time = $offer->expire_time;

            dd($childOffer->expire_time); //returns null

            $childOffer->save();
        });
    }
```

How can i do this ?!

Comment: The `$childOffer->expire_time` isn't updated until you call save

Comment: seems nothing wrong in your code

Comment: the problem is in expire_time type , all fields change if i pass data to them except this field @Sohel0415

Comment: is there any error??

Comment: nope :(  @Sohel0415

Comment: try removing self from `function (self $childOffer)`

Comment: tried..still returns null.. @Sohel0415

Comment: i tried your code and it works fine, try this where it shows null and see what it shows `dd($offer->expire_time." ".$childOffer->expire_time);`

Comment: with timestamps type? @Sohel0415

Comment: yes, i tried with created_at field which is also timestamp type

Comment: it shows first one. "2018-02-30 23:59:59  "@Sohel0415

Comment: which one it is showing, first one or last one??

Comment: first one @Sohel0415

Comment: assign to a new variable  and try dd that variable

Comment: yeah if i assign it to a new variable it changs but the model doesn't accept anything..'@Sohel0415

Comment: how can i found that why the model doesnt accept this field to change@Sohel0415?

Comment: it works on created_at field @Sohel0415

Comment: that's pretty weird

Comment: I have to fix that whatever it is :( thank you for your helps @Sohel0415

Answer (score 2):

Add `expire_time` to fillable field in your model and firt make sure to persist to database and then check

```
if ($offer->childrenOffers->count()) {

    $offer->childrenOffers->each(function (self $childOffer) use($offer) {
       $childOffer->expire_time = $offer->expire_time;     
       $childOffer->save();
       dd($childOffer->expire_time); //returns null    
    });
}
```

Comment: it's in fillable field. all fields change if i pass data to them except this field!! and i really don't know why :(

Answer (score 2):

Use `saved` or `updated` [Eloquent events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events).

Every time when you'll update the model, you can update its children.

Comment: I tried all of these but it doesnt work :( the problem is not with saving or updating...the problem is in that field type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Eloquent Event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events)

> Eloquent models fire several events, allowing you to hook into the following points in a model's lifecycle: retrieved, creating, created, updating, updated, saving, saved, deleting,  deleted, restoring, restored. Events allow you to easily execute code each time a specific model class is saved or updated in the database.

In you `Offer` model, you can add a boot method to automatically update the children when the offer is saved or updated like this:

```
public static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    //When the offer is updated
    static::updated(function ($offer) {
        $offer->childrenOffers->each(function ($child) use ($offer){
            $child->expire_time = $offer->expire_time;
            $child->save();
        });
    });
}
```